# Создание аккордеона, направить на путь правильный

Tags: javascript, pug

Есть такая структура в PUG:

```
.table-wrap
     .table-block
         .services__block.services__title.services__btn Нажать кнопку
         .table-hidden
              table.services__table

     .table-block
         .services__block.services__title.services__btn Телеграм боты
         .table-hidden
```

JS:

```
 document.querySelector('.table-wrap').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var block = event.target.closest('.table-block');

    if (block) {
      var elem = block.querySelector('.table-hidden');

      if (elem.classList.contains('active')) {
        elem.style.height = getComputedStyle(elem).height;
        elem.classList.remove('active');
        getComputedStyle(elem).height; // reflow
        elem.style.height = '';
      } else {
        elem.classList.add('active');
        var h = getComputedStyle(elem).height;
        elem.style.height = '0';
        getComputedStyle(elem).height; // reflow
        elem.style.height = h;
        setTimeout(function () { elem.style.height = '' }, 1000); // Когда закончится анимация
      }
    }
  });
```

Потому что когда открывается таблица, даётся класс `active`, а если нажму на таблицу, он уберёт его снова. Сидел часа 2 над этим.

Всё вроде как хорошо, но мне нужно, чтобы только при нажатии на кнопку `.services__btn` добавлялось в `.table-hidden` класс `.active`
А у меня не получается написать из этого код.
И чтобы первая кнопка добавляла только первому `.table-hidden` класс `.active`, можно сказать как аккордеон.

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите чтобы регистрировалось нажатие только на кнопку .service__btn - тогда стоит сделать условием начала работы именно это: *`event.target.closest('.services__btn')`*
В вашем коде вы сделали условием нажатие на любой элемент блока.

Я добавил свои фрагменты кода чтобы улучшить анимацию (возможно она у вас реализована в стилях - тогда исключите пожалуйста лишнее).
Пример с PUG можно посмотреть здесь: https://codepen.io/ilya-lokalin/pen/bGGXzmX

Ниже тот же пример с HTML:

```js
document.querySelector('.table-wrap').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  const target  = event.target;
  const block   = target.closest('.table-block');
  
  
  // Проверяем что нажата именно кнопка
  if (target.closest('.services__btn')) {
    
    if (block) {
      const elem = block.querySelector('.table-hidden');
      
      if (elem.classList.contains('active')) {
        elem.classList.remove('active');
        let elementHeight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(elem).height);
        

        //Анимация скрытия
        elem.style.opacity = '0';
        let stepDown = function () {
          elem.style.height = elementHeight + 'px';
          
          if (elementHeight-- > 0) {
            setTimeout(stepDown, 10);
          } 
        }
        setTimeout(stepDown, 10);
        
      } else {
        elem.classList.add('active');
        const heightLimit = parseInt(block.dataset.height);
        let elementHeight = 0;
        

        //Анимация показа блока
        let stepUp = function () {
          elem.style.height = elementHeight + 'px';
   
          if (elementHeight++ < heightLimit) {
            setTimeout(stepUp, 10);
          } else {
            elem.style.opacity = '1';
          }
        }
        setTimeout(stepUp, 10);
        
        }
     }
  }
});
```

```css
.services__btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrap">
    <div class="table-block" data-height="18px">
        <div class="services__block services__title services__btn">Нажать кнопку</div>
        <div class="table-hidden active">
            <table class="services__table">Какой-то текст</table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-block" data-height="18px">
        <div class="services__block services__title services__btn">Телеграм боты</div>
        <div class="table-hidden active">И тут текст</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ, всего лишь нужно было добавить  if (target.closest('.services__btn'))